# Extracting class name from parent of dynamic checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to extract the number from a class name and add it to an array but I am getting error message "Object doesn't support property or method 'parent'".
I'm just at the part of extracting the classname just now.

Thanks

```
<ul id="catbox">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-2">
        <a href="http://oursite/events/category/internal-events/">Internal Events</a>
        <ul class='children'>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-8">
                <a href="http://oursite/events/category/internal-events/civic-and-ceremonial/">Civic and Ceremonial</a>
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-6">
                <a href="http://oursite/events/category/internal-events/economy-and-skills-education-tourism-town-centre-business-events/">Economy and Skills – Education, Tourism, Town Centre, Business Events</a>
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-7">
                <a href="http://oursite/events/category/internal-events/health-and-social-care/">Health and Social Care</a>
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-13">
                <a href="http://oursite/events/category/internal-events/other-internal-events/">Other</a>
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-5">
                <a href="http://oursite/events/category/internal-events/safer-communities-vibrant-communities-leisure-trust/">Safer Communities – Vibrant Communities, Leisure Trust</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#test").load("/events/cal-page/");
    $(".cat-item").prepend("<input type=\"checkbox\" >  ");

    $(":checkbox").change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            var values = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
                return this.parent().attr('class');
            }).get();

            alert(values);

            $("#test").load("/events/cal-page/?q=" + number + "");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `.parent()` is a method of `jQuery` wrapped element. `this` in `callback` will represent `DOM` element not the `jQuery` wrapped element.

Use `return $(this).parent().attr('class');`

```js
$(".cat-item").prepend("<input type=\"checkbox\" >");
$(":checkbox").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    var values = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
      return $(this).parent().attr('class');
    }).get();
    alert(values);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="catbox">
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-2"><a href="http://oursite/events/category/internal-events/">Internal Events</a>
    <ul class='children'>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-8"><a href="http://oursite/events/category/internal-events/civic-and-ceremonial/">Civic and Ceremonial</a>
      </li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-6"><a href="http://oursite/events/category/internal-events/economy-and-skills-education-tourism-town-centre-business-events/">Economy and Skills – Education, Tourism, Town Centre, Business Events</a>
      </li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-7"><a href="http://oursite/events/category/internal-events/health-and-social-care/">Health and Social Care</a>
      </li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-13"><a href="http://oursite/events/category/internal-events/other-internal-events/">Other</a>
      </li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-5"><a href="http://oursite/events/category/internal-events/safer-communities-vibrant-communities-leisure-trust/">Safer Communities – Vibrant Communities, Leisure Trust</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery object `$(this)` instead of `this` in `map()` like following.

```
$(this).parent().attr('class');
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that your are not using a jquery element to call parent() method taht is from jQuery.

Change this line, this for $(this).

```
return $(this).parent().attr('class');
```